# How to Implement Role-Based Access Control for Functionalities and Pages in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, authorization, user-roles, conditional-rendering

I'm building a load transportation React application where different users have different roles, e.g., client and Transporter. and I would like to render different components and grant access to different functionalities based on the user’s role. For instance, Clients should have access to client-specific pages, and transporters should not be able to access those.

I haven't tried anything yet, I have been reading on google how to implement it but it seemed rather confusing.